# SQL Session State in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, session

We have a couple of existing web forms applications that use SQL session state (HttpContext.Current.Session). The sessions are shared between the applications, meaning the user doesn't have to log in twice.

I'm looking to rebuild one of our systems on ASP.Net core and for the moment want to continue using the same session database and method of storing sessions, to support the older applications at the same time.

I've looked around extensively online and it appears the structure of the SQL session database has changed quite a lot.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the old database with ASP.Net Core?
Any help or direction appreciated.

Comment: Please see this: http://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HttpContext.Current in ASP.NET Core?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571032/how-to-get-httpcontext-current-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: I saw that, but the problem is it seems to be based on a new table as per this article http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/292/configuring-sql-server-for-session-state-in-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc

Comment: Any help here would be appreciated as we're soon to kick off development and I'd love to be able to use ASP.Net Core. I'm trying to investigate alternatives of auto logging the user into the other application, but if I could use the standard database that would be brilliant.