# Trying to migrate to Core, but stuck with Middleware (old ihttpModule)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've done most of the part but here are some things that I really dont know much about..

Also how to end request/completerequest? Generate the code into .net core code

```
private static void SetCorsResponse(HttpContext context)
    {

        context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE");
        context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
        context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        **HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();**
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some more examples of your code, in particular you Controller method. The header you're tring to set is a CORS header, which is now a middleware here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Also, I don't understand what you're doing with the `CompleteRequest` call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core has removed the `HttpContext.Current`, so getting it will not be possible.You can acces the current HTTP Context from a controller using `HttpContext` .See more information here [How to get HttpContext.Current in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571032/how-to-get-httpcontext-current-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: I've done exacly like that post said, but somehow I have to Set the value of the Headers.. I know httpcontext.current isnt possible anymore, thats why I created a middleware class

Comment: Middleware no have controllers