# AspNet Core 2 No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext' sessions issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core-2.0

im using AspNet Core 2 to build an app, im having problems with sessions, can you please help?

exact error:

**No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext' has been registered.**

im using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) as guide, but seems to be not enough.

in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });//<<==
        }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseSession();//<<==

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
```

in home controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

HttpContext.Session.SetString("TestName", user.UserName);
HttpContext.Session.SetString("TestVal", user.testVal.ToString());
```

**to this point it seems to be working**, im able to navigate through different pages and i can use/check sessions in controller side.

But the problem is when im trying to use sessions in any view

View side:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject HttpContext HttpContext


@if (@HttpContext.Session.GetString("testVal").Equals("True"))
{
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
}
else
{
<td><input type="checkbox" readonly></td>
}
```

when i try to get or set sessions cshtml/view side i get the error

can you please help?

Comment: how about @HttpContext.Current.Session.GetString("testVal").Equals("True") using this line

Comment: HttpContext.Current was removed in ASP.NET Core. there is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571032/how-to-get-httpcontext-current-in-asp-net-core/38574489) about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the way to use sessions view side with asp net core 2

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
Session Value = @Context.Session.GetString("TestName")
```

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6333)

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

a temporary fix while i find a better solution is:

controller side

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("TestName", user.UserName);
HttpContext.Session.SetString("TestVal", user.testVal.ToString());
HttpContext.Session.SetString("SecurityToken", securityToken);
ViewBag.TestVal = user.testVal.ToString();
```

view side

```
@if (ViewBag.TestVal.Equals("True"))
{
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
}
else
{
<td><input type="checkbox" readonly></td>
}
```

where security token is a random long value created when the session start, this isnt the best way ... and you must verify this token each time you want to update,create or delete something, that plus AntiForgeryToken, could be the best for  a non prod tests or a first aproach...

if you know a better way please share