# Accessing Httpcontext outside controller in .net core

Tags: session, .net-core, httpcontext

I can't access Session variables outside controllers, there are over 200 examples where they advise you to add `;`

`services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

and use

```
public class DummyReference
{
        private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        public DummyReference(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            // access _httpcontextaccessor to reach sessions variables
        }
}
```

But, no-one mentions how to call this class from my controller. How can I reach that class?

If changed it to static then I need bypass construct. If I create it I need httpcontextaccessor for construct.

For who wants learn more why I approached like that, I want to write class include methods like encrypt, decrypt database tables RowIDs for masking in VIEW with value+sessionvariable to ensure its not modified.

Also I want DummyReference to be static, that way I can easily reach DummyReference.EncryptValue or DecryptValue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HttpContext.Current in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571032/how-to-get-httpcontext-current-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the same happend to me
I found the solution putting in my method into the no controller class (where I want to use it)

```
var HttpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

var vUser =  _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("user");
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't use **IHttpContextAccessor** outside of controllers. Instead, use **HttpContextAccessor**.

Like this in static classes ;

```
private static HttpContext _httpContext => new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
```

Or anywhere else. You still need service of course and the thing we do in the controllers.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0) 
 Add

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public UserRepository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) =>
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
```

Answer (score 1):

That code gets you the current HttpContext. Sessions are slightly different: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2