# Read cookies inside a static method [ ASP MVC ]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I work on a ASP.NET MVC project, I create a `Controller` named `AuthenticationController`, this controller contains a `static method` called `User_Access_Validation`.

This method check some **cookies** **values**.

So that is method code :

```
public void User_Access_Validation()
{
 if (Request.Cookies["X_8"] == null || Request.Cookies["X_5"] == null || Request.Cookies["X_T"] == null)
   {
     Response.Redirect("/Login");
   }
}
```

Everythings works good at now, but when I change this method to a `static` method I got these **four errors** in **ErrorList** in **Visual Studio**

```
Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 

Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 

Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

So please I need this method to be a `static` method, and fix this error

Comment: Request is an instance property. Try HttpContext.Current.Request

Comment: I try it but `Current` not shown in Intellisense

Comment: Um. Where does this code live (a controller like you mentioned, an api method, some class somewhere else and Request isn't what I think it is) and what version of things are you using? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.current?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: yeah I Use controller but the `Current` don't shown in intellisense and **Visual Studio** show me an error **red underline** below it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029302/5101046) helps with providing static access to `HttpContext` (which includes request and response) in ASP.NET Core. This isn't easily available because it's not a good pattern. But, as noted in the answer, it might be helpful in cases where you need to move old code into a new controller. I'm curious about why it has to be static. But I get it. Sometimes we just need things to behave a certain way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Scott Hannen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5101046/scott-hannen) Montionned in his answer, you should use `Response` and `Request` objects as parameters if you need to work with `static method`, but I think your code should have like this :

```
public static void User_Access_Validation(HttpRequestBase request, HttpResponseBase response)
{
 if (request.Cookies["X_8"] == null || request.Cookies["X_5"] == null || request.Cookies["X_T"] == null)
   {
     response.Redirect("/Login");
   }
}
```

Whats new here ? is the parameters should `base`, `HttpRequestBase` and `HttpResponseBase`

I wish this help.

Answer (score 1):

`Request` and `Response` are instance properties - they belong to a specific instance of the `Controller`.

A `static` method doesn't belong to any specific instance of the class. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members):

> Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method parameter.

I recommend reading more. For the purposes of this answer, you can't access `Request` and `Response` from a static method. What you can do, as the article says, is pass them as arguments to a static method. So you could do this:

```
public static void User_Access_Validation(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
{
 if (request.Cookies["X_8"] == null || request.Cookies["X_5"] == null || request.Cookies["X_T"] == null)
   {
     response.Redirect("/Login");
   }
}
```

Now the method isn't attempting to read those static properties. It's just using the methods passed to it. (Notice that `request` and `response` are lower-case. They're referring to the variables, not the properties which are capitalized.

You can call this static method from a non-static (instance) method. The instance method, which can access those properties, can pass them as arguments to the static method:

```
public static void User_Access_Validation(Request, Response);
```

---

[Here's another good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c) that explains the difference between static and instance (non-static) methods. It has a simple but illuminating example.

Comment: This answer is very literal. From the sound of it, unless it's for a quiz it might not help at all. Sorry.

Comment: This is a great answer and massive thanks bro for your time and your answer, I have one last question how can I create objects from `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` to pass them to the method, cause this is the first time I will work with them.

Comment: If you're calling from a non-static method then you don't have to create them. You can just pass the `Request` and `Response`. (See the last code sample at the end of the answer.) If you're calling from a static method then my answer doesn't help, because you're in the same place.