# Get link/API path in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have create a program that using .NET Framework 4.7.2 and I want to convert to .NET 6 (just for training purpose or future use.

The way when I get the link like "/jsonAPI/prxy001" in .NET 4.7.2 like this :

```
log.EndPoint = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
```

log.Endpoint is just a model

And I try to use it in .NET 6 said that "Current" is not available in HttpContext. I think the way or reference is defference. Can you tell me how?

P.S =
I generate that not in controller, but in another helper class.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571032/how-to-get-httpcontext-current-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

Inject HttpContextAccessor in the startup configureservices method like below

`services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

then inject it via constructor in any class you need

```
public class Test 
 {
    private IHttpContextAccessor context;

     public Test(IHttpContextAccessor ctx) {
      this.context = ctx;
     }
 }
```