# Does ASP.NET Dispose The HTTP Request Stream Automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the raw HTTP request body as a sting in my ASP.NET minimal API.
When I build the route like so, without declaring the C# object that the request is supposed to be mapped to, I am able to read the stream ok:

```
app.MapPost("/test", async (
    HttpContext httpContext
    ) =>
{
    try
    {
        httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpRequest.Body);
        reader.DiscardBufferedData();
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string request = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request))
            Console.WriteLine($"stream pos: {httpContext.Request.Body.Position} " +
            $"stream length : {httpContext.Request.Body.Length}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
});
```

However, when I declare the object, the request string is empty even though I have reset the seek position to 0:

```
app.MapPost("/test", async (
    HttpContext httpContext,
    TestRequest testRequest
    ) =>
{
    try
    {
        httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpRequest.Body);
        reader.DiscardBufferedData();
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string request = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request))
            Console.WriteLine($"stream pos: {httpContext.Request.Body.Position} " +
            $"stream length : {httpContext.Request.Body.Length}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
});
```

This is what is printed to the console:`stream pos: 0 stream length : 0`.
So, I would like to confirm whether .NET automatically clears/disposes of the stream after it tries to map it to the C# object.

Comment: c# uses a garbage disposal (GD) to dispose objects.  GD only runs when there is time to perform disposal or when the memory is needed.  c# is managed and has lots of protection to prevent exceptions.  So every c# object has an link count of number of times a class object is referenced.  GD check the link count before disposing an object.  So in your case the stream object will not be disposed because another object is linked to the stream (the request).  The stream will not be disposed until the request is disposed or the stream in the request is set to null.

Comment: Are you sure you are reaching the posted code?  Add break point to be sure.

Comment: I don't think you're accessing the request content properly here. Take a look at the answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589539/how-do-i-get-the-raw-request-body-from-the-request-content-object-using-net-4-a

Comment: I didn't know my vote to close it as a duplicate would automatically close it so if that doesn't answer the question let me know and we can reopen it.

Comment: @jdweng Most of that first comment is complete disinformation: It's called Garbage Collection not disposal. It doesn't fully dispose unmanaged objects, like a `Stream` might contain, you need a `using`. The object does not have a link count, GC goes down the tree of objects looking for references each time it runs. Streams can still be disposed if you use a `using`.

Comment: You can't seek a network stream, you can only read forward. Why are you calling `DiscardBufferedData` anyway?

Comment: Hi @MikePerrenoud I already checked that thread before posting this question. It doesn't answer my question. Note how I said in my question that simply adding the ```TestRequest testRequest``` when setting my route is enough to cause the stream to have a length of zero. Without that declation, I am able to read the stream ok and get the desired output.

Comment: @jdweng I can confirm I am reaching the posted code. As I stated in my question, this ``` stream pos: 0 stream length : 0``` is getting printed to the console.

Comment: @Charlieface I call ```DiscardBufferedData``` in order to synchronize the internal buffer and the underlying stream. Here is the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_IO_StreamReader_DiscardBufferedData

Comment: In that instance, you already have the reader. Here you are creating a new reader, you don't need it. If the stream really is seekable, seek it before you create the reader.

Comment: @Charlieface My original question still stands though. Why the difference between the two scenarios I posted.

Comment: One assumes that ASP.NET has already parsed the request in `TestRequest` using the JSON deserializer, so you are too late. You need to move `httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();` into a middleware which runs before that.

Comment: @Charlieface your solution worked